# Load iFrame content with Highcharts graphs only when focussed (with PagePiling.js)

Tags: javascript, iframe, highcharts, pagepiling.js

I am using [pagePiling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js), and have added a couple of extra sections. These are using iFrames to load Highcharts graphs, as can be seen [here](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/extras/climate_change_story_graphs_2.php). However, at the moment, all 12 iFrames respectively the graphs are being loaded, which makes the user wait a few seconds unnecessarily on the first page (and consumes bandwidth).

Is there any way to load the iFrames only the moment they are getting the focus? Or perhaps, a bit smoother, to load the next-upcoming graph while the current graph is being focussed on? I haven't really found something like this.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Have you tried to init chart in afterLoad method?

Comment: @SebastianBochan is right. Use the fullpage.js callbacks such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave` to modify the `src` of the iframe (lazy loading) or to initialize highcharts.

Comment: Thanks for those hints. However, not being a pro in jQuery/javascript programming, I have difficulties understanding what code should go into those events in order to load the iFrames' source only one-page-before it's being displayed. Haven't found anything working in that direction. In my mind, there would be only one iFrame in the HTML code, and the sources for the other graphs would be allocated to the one and single iFrame then on the page, right? Sounds logical. But how to achieve this? Any working examples somewhere? Didn't find something.